# Starting a sentence with the phrase "I say"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Should I put the phrase "I say" at the beginning or end of a sentence and do I need to use a comma before or after the phrase?

I mean, should the sentence be:

> I say, Hillary for president!

or

> Hillary for president, I say.

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence just sounds and reads better to me, but both are grammatically correct.

I'd also point out that saying the first sentence would be redundant in speech, but would be used for emphasis. The sort of situation which would be most applicable would be if you in a group with multiple conversations. So you'd start off with "i say ..."  to divert attention to you.

If I were writing the first sentence then I'd might put *Hillary for president* in quotes. This would be particularly true for the first sentence in a paragraph where I'm explaining why I want Hillary to be president.

Comment: I would say that much of the difference lies in emphasis. The first is far more emphatic and sounds like a declaration. The second more like a response to a comment made by someone else and thus more likely to be subdued in tone, even if declarative.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.  This is entirely a stylistic decision and depends on the situation and the context.  So the answer might be different for a play than for a novel.  It might depend if the sentence was dialog or not, and might depend on the kind of dialog.